# Is There a de Rham Homology

Tags: reference-request, differential-geometry, homology-cohomology

For differential manifold category, we can introduce the differential form to make up a cochain, and then get the de Rham cohomology group.

My question is that if we use $\text{Hom}$ functor to get the dual chain of the cochain, then does the new homology satisfies the Eilenberg-Steenrod axioms? If so, is there any reference to study it?

Any advice is helpful. Thank you.

Comment: This isn't an answer so I'm leaving it as a comment -- it sounds like you'd be interested in currents: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_%28mathematics%29

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/16657/de-rham-homology